# Replacing NAs with existing data when merging two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

I would like to merge two dataframes. There are some shared variables and some different variables and there are different numbers of rows in each dataframe. The dataframes share some rows, but not all. And both dataframes have missing data that the other my have.

DF1:

| name | age | weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 7 | 54 | 112 |
| Dave | 5 | 50 | NA |
| Larry | NA | 42 | 73 |
| Rob | 1 | 30 | 43 |

DF2:

| name | age | weight | height | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 7 | NA | 112 | 2 |
| Dave | NA | 50 | 103 | 1 |
| Larry | 3 | NA | 73 | NA |
| Rob | 1 | 30 | NA | NA |
| John | 6 | 60 | NA | 1 |
| Tom | 8 | 61 | 112 | 2 |

I want to merge these two dataframes together by the shared columns (name, age, weight, and height). However, I want NAs to be overridden, such that if one of the two dataframes has a value where the other has NA, I want the value to be carried through into the third dataframe. Ideally, the last dataframe should only have NAs when both DF1 and DF2 had NAs in that same location.

**Ideal Data Frame**

| name | age | weight | height | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 7 | 54 | 112 | 2 |
| Dave | 5 | 50 | 103 | 1 |
| Larry | 3 | 42 | 73 | NA |
| Rob | 1 | 30 | 43 | NA |
| John | 6 | 60 | NA | 1 |
| Tom | 8 | 61 | 112 | 2 |

I've been using full_join and left_join, but I don't know how to merge these in such a way that NAs are replaced with actual data (if it is present in one of the dataframes). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge two uneven dataframes by ID and fill in missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871585/merge-two-uneven-dataframes-by-id-and-fill-in-missing-values)

Comment: You could do a "coalescing join" https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/

Comment: What should happen if df1 and df2 both contain non-NA values, but different? Also, I am assuming the "name" column contains unique values?

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical case that `rows_patch()` from `dplyr` can treat.

```r
library(dplyr)

rows_patch(df2, df1, by = "name")

   name age weight height grade
1   Tim   7     54    112     2
2  Dave   5     50    103     1
3 Larry   3     42     73    NA
4   Rob   1     30     43    NA
5  John   6     60     NA     1
6   Tom   8     61    112     2
```

---

###### Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Tim", "Dave", "Larry", "Rob"), age = c(7L, 
5L, NA, 1L), weight = c(54L, 50L, 42L, 30L), height = c(112L, 
NA, 73L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("Tim", "Dave", "Larry", "Rob", "John", 
"Tom"), age = c(7L, NA, 3L, 1L, 6L, 8L), weight = c(NA, 50L, 
NA, 30L, 60L, 61L), height = c(112L, 103L, 73L, NA, NA, 112L), 
grade = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  bind_rows(df1) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(age:grade, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  distinct

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   name    age weight height grade
#>   <chr> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1 Tim       7     54    112     2
#> 2 Dave      5     50    103     1
#> 3 Larry     3     42     73    NA
#> 4 Rob       1     30     43    NA
#> 5 John      6     60     NA     1
#> 6 Tom       8     61    112     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `powerjoin` package suggested as an answer to the question in the first comment, which I had never heard of before.

However, if you want to avoid using extra packages, you can do it in base R. This approach also avoids having to explicitly name each column - the `dplyr` approaches suggested in the comments do not do that, although perhaps could be modified.

```r
# Load data

df1  <- read.table(text = "name age weight  height
Tim 7   54  112
Dave    5   50  NA
Larry   NA  42  73
Rob 1   30  43", header=TRUE)
df2  <- read.table(text = "name age weight  height  grade
Tim 7   NA  112 2
Dave    NA  50  103 1
Larry   3   NA  73  NA
Rob 1   30  NA  NA
John    6   60  NA  1
Tom 8   61  112 2", header=TRUE)


df3  <- merge(df1, df2, by = "name", all = TRUE, sort=FALSE)

# Coalesce the common columns
common_cols  <- names(df1)[names(df1)!="name"]
df3[common_cols]  <- lapply(common_cols, function(col) {
    coalesce(df3[[paste0(col, ".x")]], df3[[paste0(col, ".y")]])
}) 

# Select desired columns
df3[names(df2)]

#    name age weight height grade
# 1   Tim   7     54    112     2
# 2  Dave   5     50    103     1
# 3 Larry   3     42     73    NA
# 4   Rob   1     30     43    NA
# 5  John   6     60     NA     1
# 6   Tom   8     61    112     2
```

There are advantages to using base R, but powerjoin looks like an interesting package too.

Comment: Note that `coalesce` is from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Good point! That's what happens when you have `dplyr` loaded all the time!