# full_join with pre-existing data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframes `df.old` and `df.new`. `df.old` has a group variable `grp` and in group 2 there are missing values. These missings can be found in `df.new`.

So, I would like to make a full_join of both dataframes using the `PID` variable as the key. The missings should be filled up using the data from `df.new`. However, `df.new` has also some additional columns, that should also be included in the final dataframe. And it also has some additional rows that should be included.

So the desired output should have PIDs from 1 to 23, the columns A_t1, B_t1, C_t1, A_t2 and no missings.

```r
size.old <- 20
set.seed(1)

df.old <- data.frame(PID = 1:size.old,
                     grp = sample(1:3, size.old, replace = TRUE),
                     A_t1 = sample(1:10, size.old, replace = TRUE), 
                     B_t1 = sample(1:10, size.old, replace = TRUE), 
                     C_t1 = sample(1:10, size.old, replace = TRUE)
                     ) %>%
          mutate(A_t1 = ifelse(grp == 2, NA, A_t1),
                 B_t1 = ifelse(grp == 2, NA, A_t1),
                 C_t1 = ifelse(grp == 2, NA, A_t1)) %>%
  arrange(grp)

#> df.old
#   PID grp A_t1 B_t1 C_t1
# 1    1   1    5    5    5
# 2    3   1    9    9    9
# 3    5   1    5    5    5
# 4   12   1    3    3    3
# 5   13   1    6    6    6
# 6   14   1   10   10   10
# 7   20   1    9    9    9
# 8    4   2   NA   NA   NA
# 9    8   2   NA   NA   NA
# 10   9   2   NA   NA   NA
# 11  15   2   NA   NA   NA
# 12  16   2   NA   NA   NA
# 13  17   2   NA   NA   NA
# 14  18   2   NA   NA   NA
# 15   2   3    5    5    5
# 16   6   3    5    5    5
# 17   7   3    2    2    2
# 18  10   3    1    1    1
# 19  11   3    4    4    4
# 20  19   3   10   10   10

df.new <- data.frame(PID = c(4, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23),
                     A_t1 = sample(1:10, size=11, replace = TRUE),
                     A_t2 = sample(1:10, size=11, replace = TRUE)
)

# > df.new
#   PID A_t1 A_t2
# 1    4    2   10
# 2    8    2    8
# 3    9    3   10
# 4   15    1    4
# 5   16    2    5
# 6   17    3    9
# 7   18    3    5
# 8   20    3    7
# 9   21    8    5
# 10  22    9    6
# 11  23    2    4
```

```r
# This will just rename the common columns instead of filling them
full_join(df.old, df.new, by = "PID")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Ok I see. What you need is `coalesce_join` provided by @alistaire https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/.

Also see here here [Replacing NAs with existing data when merging two dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029443/replacing-nas-with-existing-data-when-merging-two-dataframes-in-r)

```
coalesce_join <- function(x, y, 
                          by = NULL, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), 
                          join = dplyr::full_join, ...) {
  joined <- join(x, y, by = by, suffix = suffix, ...)
  # names of desired output
  cols <- union(names(x), names(y))
  
  to_coalesce <- names(joined)[!names(joined) %in% cols]
  suffix_used <- suffix[ifelse(endsWith(to_coalesce, suffix[1]), 1, 2)]
  # remove suffixes and deduplicate
  to_coalesce <- unique(substr(
    to_coalesce, 
    1, 
    nchar(to_coalesce) - nchar(suffix_used)
  ))
  
  coalesced <- purrr::map_dfc(to_coalesce, ~dplyr::coalesce(
    joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[1])]], 
    joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[2])]]
  ))
  names(coalesced) <- to_coalesce
  
  dplyr::bind_cols(joined, coalesced)[cols]
}

coalesce_join(df.old, df.new, by = "PID")

   PID grp A_t1 B_t1 C_t1 A_t2
1    8   1    3    3    3    6
2   12   1    7    7    7   NA
3   13   1    6    6    6   NA
4   17   1    1    1    1    9
5   18   1    1    1    1    6
6   20   1    3    3    3    6
7    2   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
8    3   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
9    4   2    2   NA   NA    9
10   6   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
11   7   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
12  10   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
13  16   2    2   NA   NA    5
14  19   2   NA   NA   NA   NA
15   1   3    6    6    6   NA
16   5   3    1    1    1   NA
17   9   3    2    2    2   10
18  11   3    4    4    4   NA
19  14   3    9    9    9   NA
20  15   3    8    8    8    8
21  21  NA    6   NA   NA    8
22  22  NA    2   NA   NA    5
23  23  NA    7   NA   NA    8
```

**First answer:**
Instead of joining we should use `match`:

```
library(dplyr)

df.old %>%
  mutate(A_t1 = ifelse(is.na(A_t1), df.new$A_t1[match(PID, df.new$PID)], A_t1))
```

```
   PID grp A_t1 B_t1 C_t1
1    1   1    5    5    5
2    3   1    9    9    9
3    5   1    5    5    5
4   12   1    3    3    3
5   13   1    6    6    6
6   14   1   10   10   10
7   20   1    9    9    9
8    4   2    9   NA   NA
9    8   2    7   NA   NA
10   9   2    7   NA   NA
11  15   2    3   NA   NA
12  16   2    6   NA   NA
13  17   2    2   NA   NA
14  18   2   10   NA   NA
15   2   3    5    5    5
16   6   3    5    5    5
17   7   3    2    2    2
18  10   3    1    1    1
19  11   3    4    4    4
20  19   3   10   10   10
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know the `match()`-function before. Unfortunately, the real dataframes have a lot more columns, so it would be cumbersome to define every column within the `mutate()`-function. Furthermore, there are columns that only exist in df.new and also need to be added (in the example above `A_t2`). Maybe there is a more general solution?